# Unable to install pyautogui on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pyautogui

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I am unable to install `pyautogui`

I followed installation steps exactly as in docs, but when I run `pip3 install pyautogui` I get:

```
Collecting pyobjc-core (from pyautogui)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d3/f5/07579f2986f2eb639932626f69a082598f5e6d4535e1f54a331d9efa97d7/pyobjc-core-5.2.tar.gz
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: running egg_info
    error: PyObjC requires macOS to build
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-48511rea/pyobjc-core/
```

The steps before are fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not even on macOS, why would I need that? intalled it too, but it didnt help

Comment: It seems your `setuptools` ignored [`platform_system=="Darwin"`](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/9c9569bf0b0b20a099abef228e1b90a800cd9c07/setup.py#L26) condition. Try to upgrade `pip` and `setuptools`.

Comment: @phd I tried upgrading both, but still getting the same error.

python 3 version: Python 3.6.9 //

pip3 version: pip 19.1.1  ///


I used this doc to upgrade: https://bigchaindb-server.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/appendices/install-latest-pip.html

Comment: Try installing through a whl file instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/350) the issue is with the Ubuntu version. Upgrade your OS to resolve the problem.